# Показать всплывающее окно на сайте один раз в неделю

Tags: javascript

Есть всплывающее окно, которое появляется после прокрутки до определённого блока.

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){   
    var $element = $('.footer');
    $counter = 0;
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
  //Если скролл до конца елемента
  //var offset = $element.offset().top + $element.height();
  //Если скролл до начала елемента
  var offset = $element.offset().top;

  if (scroll > offset && $counter == 0) {
    $('#block').fadeIn(500);
    $counter = 1;
  }
});
$('.btn').click(function(){
 $('#block').slideUp();
});

   });
   </script>
```

```css
#block{
 display: none;
 position: fixed;
 top: 15px;
 right: 15px;
 color: #fff;
 background: #4CAF50;
 padding: 10px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 width: 200px;
 box-shadow: 0 13px 20px -5px #3a3a3a;
 font-family: Arial;
 text-align: center;
}
.btn{
    background: #FF9800;
    border: 2px solid #795548;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="block">Текст, написанный в окне<br>
 Просто закройте окно.
 <input type="button" class="btn" value="Закрыть">
</div>

 <div class="footer"><p>Footer</p></div>
```

Этот код работает нормально. Как сделать так, чтобы при закрытии окна, это окно не всплывало у одного пользователя в течение недели.

Я нашёл следующий скрипт, который работает по нужному принципу с cookie:

```js
<script src="/catalog/view/javascript/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#setCookie").click(function () {
$.cookie("popup", "", { expires:0, path: '/' });
$("#bg_popup").hide();
});
 
if ( $.cookie("popup") == null )
{
setTimeout(function(){
$("#bg_popup").show();
}, 4000)
}
else { $("#bg_popup").hide();
}
});
</script>
```

```css
#bg_popup{
position: fixed;
z-index: 99999;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
display: none;}
   
#popup {
 background: #FF9800;
    border: 2px solid #795548;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
width: 350px;
margin: 25% auto;
padding: 5px 20px;
position: relative;}
   
.close{
display:block;
position:absolute;
top:5px;
right:5px;
width:20px;
height:20px;
color:#555;
background:#1BA600;
cursor:pointer;}
```

```html
<div id="bg_popup">
  <div id="popup">
  <a  id="setCookie" class="close" href="#" title="Закрыть" onclick="document.getElementById('bg_popup').style.display='none'; return false;">X</a>
<h1>Пример</h1>
<p>Модальное окно с задержкой в 4 секунды, которое появляется раз в сутки.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Отдельно код с cookie тоже работает. Но вот скрестить скрипт по cookie со скриптом открытия при скроле до футера у меня не получается.

Comment: Ну проверяшь `if(cooka) { твой код 1 в 1 }`. Всё как ты делаешь, только оборачиваешь свой код в проверку куки. Там никакой магии не должно быть.

Comment: @allaurross Или после выполнения открытия окна ставить триггер в куки(без разницы какое название. А при загрузке страницы проверять этот параметр в куки. Если триггер, к примеру, 1, то Выполнять скрипт, если триггер 2, то выполнять второй скрипт.

Comment: #Alex Sazonov сообщение моё обрезали до неузнаваемости.  Поэтому скорее всего и вопрос мой не ясен. У меня мало знаний оформить правильно код. Поэтому я и попросил здесь помощи. Но тут, по ходу, все яйца подрезают :). Я пробовал применить ваше предложение, но моя криворукость пользы не принесла. Не могли бы вы показать пример на моём первом коде. Тоесть как к первому коду подключить куки.

Comment: #Denis640Kb Извините , но в меру своих знаний из вашего сообщения я вообще ничего не понял :)